# Background processing java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, soa

Pardon my ignorance if this is a basic question.

I want to understand how can I return control from a module and start processing in background?

Lets start component A calls component B. Component B does some basic processing, starts a background thread and immediately returns control to A. Whenever background thread completes its processing it is going to store the result in a persistence store. Whole processing by this background thread is time consuming and A cannot wait until background thread finishes off.

```
Component A {
  Http Call component B
}

Component B {
  // Got request from component A
  start background thread();
  return; // don't wait till background thread finishes off
}

background thread() {
 // time consuming task
}
```

How can I achieve this behavior in java? I don't think it is entirely asynchronous form of processing since communication is happening over http connection that has timeout settings.

Update:

```
 Component A:
 Receives Http call 


 Component B:

 Approach1:

 Runnable runnable = new MyThread();
 new Thread(runnable).start();

 Approach2:

 ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 exec.execute(new MyThread());
 exec.shutdown();
```

Both of the above mentioned approaches helped me to start background processing and return immediate control to A.

Comment: Have you looked at the concurrency utilities? If not, have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use threads at a raw level is good solution for some easy proof of concepts, but I strongly suggest at least try to use the concurrent API from java, you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). and a good tutorial is [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/index.html)

The simplest approach is to create a Callable object that contains the instruction you want to execute in background.

```
Callable myInstructions = new Callable<ObjectToReturn>() {
         public ObjectToReturncall() {
           return object.methodCall();
       }}
```

Using the `ExecutorService` submit this callable to expect a Future object.

```
Future<ObjectToReturn> future = executor.submit(myInstructions);
//Do anything else as this wont be blocked ..
```

Future API have a set of method to ask if the task is already completed.

```
if(future.isDone()) // Ask if the task is done
    ObjectToReturn solution = future.get()   // Get the result
```

Very simple to use the Future [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) .

**EDIT**

If you dont expect any response from the Future api, just do an operation you could use

```
Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        testA.abc();
        return null;
    }
});
```

Other option if you dont want to receive a result or get a response, just fire a thread will be

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);`
executor.execute(new RunnableClass());
```

Also avoid call shutdown on [ExecutorService](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html#executorservice-usage) , do that just until the end of the process, when you dont have more time to do, in spring or container fwks the container is in charge of shutdown the `ExecutorService` once the app has been shutdown

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try it out.

Comment: Hey, I was able to implement this by using both approaches listed above. Can you suggest if this is the right thing to do here. I don''t want to get result so haven't used callable.

Comment: Also I am not sure whether calling shutdown on executor service is right thing to do or not. Since my component A will get http call multiple times, it will start one background thread for processing everytime it gets call and then shutdown the executorservice. Also component A can get call in parallel as well.

Comment: You get a very good point about the executorservice, it is better to manage a pool of threads that can be reusable, I will update my answer to reflect my comments

Comment: Thanks.. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to create a new java `Thread` with the background processing logic as parameter.

```
void componentB() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Time consuming task.
        }
    }).start();
    // The method continues without stopping.
}
```

In later versions of java, you can also use the `ForkJoinPool`-class to achieve this:

```
public class Main {

    private final ExecutorService executor = new ForkJoinPool();

    void componentA() {
        componentB();
    }

    void componentB() {
        executor.execute(this::timeConsumingTask);
        // The method continues without stopping.
    }

    private void timeConsumingTask() {
        // Time consuming task.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want the HTTP call to return before the background processing is complete, your pseudocode is perfectly valid for Java.

At the next level of detail, check out the Javadoc for `Thread`, `Runnable`, and the `java.nio` library classes.